# Mobile site hight error Running Adobe Muse v7

Tags: html, ios, iphone, adobe, muse

I am having a problem with adobe Muse changing the height of the site when previewing on iPhone 6. The dimensions of the site are correct yet i have still got an extended vertical white line under the page.

Any suggestions?

Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

Using the rectangle tool you are able to make a square / rectangle shape of the desired background space / area.

You can use the fill tool to further fill the background with an image.

I hope this helps